# Result from formula is incorrect due to more than 255 characters

Tags: excel, formula

Hope I can explain this properly. Below is my formula to return the data last (not the latest) entered in a column:

**=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(REPT("z",255),A:A))**

Instead of returning the last value, it returns the second last value. I assume this has something to do with cell containing more 255 characters.

Is there a way to get around it? I thought simply changing "255" to "350" would fix the issue (clearly it returned an error).

Cheers Mal

Comment: Cell A1 = REQUIRES 2x BATTERIES AND 1x EXTENSION CORD. Cell A2 = BATTERIES ARE NOT TO BE DELIVERED WITHOUT AN ASSESSMENT OF THE INITIAL DELIVERY. RISK IS MEDIUM HOWEVER WE BELIEVE WITH FURTHER ASSESSMENT THAT CHANGES TO THE QFT WILL RESULT IN LOWER RISK. PRIORITISATION OF WORKLOAD BETWEEN THE TEAM HAS INFLUENCED THE AVAILABILITY OF STAFF WITHIN THE MONTH OF APRIL.           **Hope that answers your question.

Comment: They are the only two cells entered so far however in future the column could have up to 300 entries. =MATCH("zzzzz",A:A) returns one less than the occupied cell in column A.

Comment: Ahhhh well thank you. I just learnt something. So there is no way to return a cell holding more than 255 characters that you know of?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the value in the last occupied cell could you not just use:

```
=index(A:A, counta(A:A), 1)
```

Comment: Cheers rgo so much! The issue was not so much getting the value of the last occupied cell, it was more if the cell contained more than 255 characters. Your formula works for more than 255! Thank you.